# OpenMP parallelization of two do-loops with condition on indexes

Tags: fortran, openmp, nested-loops

I've tried to parallelize a code contains such a double do-loop. It's not efficient for sure, but that's not a big problem now. 
The output tauv is NaN. That is the first problem.

The second problem is that Intel compiler gives fatal error with number of threads less than maximum number of threads (equals 8 for my machine).

How could I treat those problems?

```
            !$omp parallel do   private(i,j,    ro11,ro21,ro12,ro22,        &
                                                u11,u21,u12,u22,            &
                                                v11,v21,v12,v22,            &
                                                es11,es21,es12,es22,        &
                                                p11,p21,p12,p22,            &
                                                te11,te21,te12,te22,        &
                                                emu11,emu21,emu12,emu22)    &
                            shared(i1l, i2l, j1l, j2l, emumax, tauv, tauvij, ro, u, v, es) 
            do i=i1l+2,i2l-2,2
                do j=j1l+2,j2l-2,2
                    if (i.le.niii.and.i.ge.0.and.j.ge.0.and.j.le.nj.or.&
                        i.le.ni.and.i.ge.niik.and.j.gt.njjv.and.j.le.nj.or.&
                        i.le.ni.and.i.ge.niik.and.j.ge.0.and.j.lt.njjn&
                        .or.i.gt.niii.and.i.lt.niik.and.j.gt.njj0+i-niii&
                        .or.i.gt.niii.and.i.lt.niik.and.j.lt.njj0-i+niii) then
                    ro11=ro(i-1,j-1)
                    ro21=ro(i+1,j-1)
                    ro12=ro(i-1,j+1)
                    ro22=ro(i+1,j+1)
                    u11=u(i-1,j-1)
                    u21=u(i+1,j-1)
                    u12=u(i-1,j+1)
                    u22=u(i+1,j+1)
                    v11=v(i-1,j-1)
                    v21=v(i+1,j-1)
                    v12=v(i-1,j+1)
                    v22=v(i+1,j+1)
                    es11=es(i-1,j-1)
                    es21=es(i+1,j-1)
                    es12=es(i-1,j+1)
                    es22=es(i+1,j+1)
                    p11=(es11-0.5*ro11*(u11*u11+v11*v11))*ga1
                    p21=(es21-0.5*ro21*(u21*u21+v21*v21))*ga1
                    p12=(es12-0.5*ro12*(u12*u12+v12*v12))*ga1
                    p22=(es22-0.5*ro22*(u22*u22+v22*v22))*ga1
                    te11=p11/ro11   
                    te21=p21/ro21
                    te12=p12/ro12
                    te22=p22/ro22
                    emu11=te11**1.5*(1.0+s1)/(te11+s1)
                    emu21=te21**1.5*(1.0+s1)/(te21+s1)
                    emu12=te12**1.5*(1.0+s1)/(te12+s1)
                    emu22=te22**1.5*(1.0+s1)/(te22+s1)
                    emumax=emu11
                    if (emu21.gt.emumax) then
                        emumax=emu21
                    end if
                    if (emu12.gt.emumax) then
                        emumax=emu12
                    end if
                    if (emu22.gt.emumax) then
                        emumax=emu22
                    end if
                    tauvij=re*flkv*hx*hx/emumax
                    if (tauvij .le. tauv) then
                        tauv=tauvij
                    endif
                endif
                enddo
            enddo
            !$omp end parallel do
```

Comment: Welcome, use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. Your code samples should contain the declarations of all your variables and be compilable and testable. Please do read  [mcve]. Please show such a complete example and the complete output of the code including all error messages.

Comment: @VladimirF, Well the minimal reproducible example is [here](https://gist.github.com/olekravchenko/6bef56b19784606c5336012173e10246). The thing is that it executes without error, but OpenMP do-loop computes more slowly than sequential one.

Comment: The minimal example should be *within the question itself* not in a link in a comment. Please understand this is not a debugging service so try to make some.effort to reduce the code be removing unnecesary stuff and still.keeping the problem.

Answer (score 0):

> The thing is that it executes without error, but OpenMP do-loop computes more slowly than sequential one...

From your [reproducible example](https://gist.github.com/olekravchenko/6bef56b19784606c5336012173e10246):

1.) Your code is only using 1 thread (?) in OpenMP region:

```
  ! Set number of threads
  nthreads = 1
  call omp_set_num_threads(nthreads)
  print *, 'The number of threads are used is ', omp_get_max_threads ( )
```

I would avoid the `call omp_set_num_threads()`. Insted, specify number of threads with environmental variable OMP_NUM_THREADS. For unix machine: `export OMP_NUM_THREADS=<number of threads>`

2.) In your "reproducible" example, the parallelized loop (line 312) is missing private/shared declarations? From what you wrote above, fix to:

```
!$omp parallel do default(private) shared(i1l, i2l, j1l, j2l, emumax, tauv, tauvij, ro, u, v, es)
```

With all of the above, the result I get from my machine (4c/4t) using GNU Fortran compiler is:

```
...
Executed time in SEQ code is   60.2720146    
...
Executed time in OMP code is   27.1342430
```

Comment: *" you are using Intel Fortran compiler set environment variable OMP_NUM_THREADS."* Why Intel Fortran? This is the standard OpenMP way. I never use `omp_set_num_threads`.

Comment: I agree with you. In GNU Fortran `OMP_get_max_threads()` returns max number of threads even if OMP_NUM_THREADS is not set.

Comment: There are also a race condition on emumax whjich should be dealt with by using a reductio, and on tauv. (Also consider what happens if emumax changes after it is updated but before tauvij is computed; is that reasonable?)